# How to use the current Chrome Engine for Cordova Apps?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, web-applications

I have a very big problem and unfortunately I cannot find a solution. Help from some professionals would be really great. Thanks!

**The little problem**

I have a Angular Web App / Android App using Cordova. My app needs at least the Chrome Engine 50 to support all functions and looks right. Unfortunately I noticed that there are many devices that use a much older version. Also the devices do not use a common source for the Chrome Engine. Some use the Chrome Browser itself or the Android System WebView. In these two cases I can tell my testers, install the two things and then it works. Currently I check at the start of the app which version is installed and if it is less than 50 I show an info that users have to update ther apps / components particularly important here the two things (Chrome Browser itself or the Android System WebView). I rather say my users that they should update all ther apps because some hardware manufacturers have their own apps that include the Chrome Engine. That alone I find very unpleasant.

**The biger problem**

But it is worse with devices that have their own Chrome Engine built into the firmware. So one that you can not update at all via the apps update only just the hardware manufacturer of the phone can update them with firmware updates. So many cheap devices that don't get any more updates simply fall out and bring me possibly bad ratings.

What can you do?
Maybe someone has an idea? Because this way I can put my app in the store from Android 4.4 on but even 6.0 devices have older Chrome Engine versions in their firmwares. Can't I provide a chrome engine version or say I use it there from Chrome or from the Android system WebView? I'm really on the edge and need a clever solution.

I would be very happy about some help or exchange. Thanks a lot.

Best regards

Robi

Comment: There used to be the crosswalk project before that would have solved your issue, but I think it's deprecated now

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually a good idea the project but unfortunately not up to date as it looks like. :(